# hide inital character in a titile class css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

so I have a site which I Started managing a while back so still bee getting my head around how the previous person designed parts of the site, unfortunately, I'm stuck with the previously built system mostly.

so I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can hide a specific character   so let's say I have a title which is

z FULL COURSE platinum BUNDLE FOR CARE STAFF

if I wanted  to get rid of the z I could use

```
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 0px !important;
}
```

which unfortunately  means I hide all the first characters

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting all the `p` tags, select only the ones you're interested in.

One way is to add a `class` to the relevant tags, e.g.

```
<p class="title">z FULL COURSE platinum BUNDLE FOR CARE STAFF</p>
```

and change your CSS to select just those `p` tags:

```
p.title::first-letter {
    font-size: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, the titles are programticly generated so I can place an identifier in single titles I did think of trying this here's the page its on https://yourhippo.com/course-search/?wpv_post_search=z&wpv_aux_current_post_id=2718&wpv_view_count=874-TCPID2718#

Comment: CSS doesn't support "character selection". So its not really possible with CSS alone - JavaScript would work.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Looked at your code and AFAIK there is no way to select by content with just css.
You can:

- use JS for this(using regex)
- select by something unique each `h1` and remove z (eg `h1[onclick="showModal(2785)"]`
- (sick one, do not recomennd due to security) copy content of tag to some attribute (eg `data-content=""`) and then, you can select elemnts using `h1[data-content^="z "]`

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

---

you need to specify in which `p` you want to hide first letter. You can use some identifier class/id or use `:nth-child`, if you have fixed number of paragraphs and you know its parent

```css
p#hide-z::first-letter, .container > p:nth-child(3)::first-letter{
    font-size: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p id="hide-z">z FULL COURSE platinum BUNDLE FOR CARE STAFF</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum dolor...</p>
<p>z FULL COURSE platinum BUNDLE FOR CARE STAFF</p>
</div>
```

Comment: the issue is the product details are auto-generated on the system so I cant add an identifier without adding it to every product  I was hoping there would be a way to target the first letter if it was z you can see the products here  https://yourhippo.com/course-search/?wpv_post_search=z&wpv_aux_current_post_id=2718&wpv_view_count=874-TCPID2718

Comment: @user3565700 updated answer, hope, this will help